# compare values of two dataframes based on certain filter conditions and then get count

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am new to spark. I am writing a pyspark code where I have two dataframes such that :

DATAFRAME-1:

```
NAME BATCH MARKS 
A     1     44
B     15    50
C     45    99
D     2     18
```

DATAFRAME-2:

```
NAME  MARKS 
A       36
B       100
C       23
D       67
```

I want my output as a comparison between these two dataframes such that I can store the counts as my variables.

for instance,

improvedStudents = 1 (since D belongs to batch 1-15 and has improved his score)

badPerformance = 2 (A,B have performed bad since they belong between batch 1-15 and their marks are lesser than before)

neutralPerformance = 1 (C because even if his marks went down, he belongs to batch 45 that we dont want to consider)

This is just an example out of a complex problem I'm trying to solve.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If the data is as in your example why don't you just join them and create new columns for every metric that you have:

```
val df = df1.withColumnRenamed("MARKS", "PRE_MARKS")
.join(df2.withColumnRenamed("MARKS", "POST_MARKS"), Seq("NAME"))
.withColumn("Evaluation", 
    when(col("BATCH") > 15, lit("neutral"))
    .when(col("PRE_MARKS") gt col("POST_MARKS"), lit("bad")) 
    .when(col("POST_MARKS") gt col("PRE_MARKS"), lit("improved")) 
    .otherwise(lit("neutral"))
    .groupBy("Evaluation")
    .count
```

Comment: The problem I forgot to mention is, when I do a join there is an additional column in the DF-1 , which identifies a row as unique. The columns (lets say "tag"). The tag column is not present in DF-2 and if I do a join on just "name", it will give me inaccurate results

Comment: How are the two tables related then if not by `name` column? Can you edit your question with more details about your actual problem?